# Audio will not play when awakened from sleep mode (android)

Tags: android, media-player, alarm, soundpool

I'm writing an Android alarm app. I can get the activity to come up all right when the alarm is triggered (it wakes the phone up, turns off the keyguard and shows the alarm view), but I can't for the life of me get the alarm to sound if the device is in sleep mode when the alarm goes off. (It does sound perfectly when the device is awake and the keyguard is on.) I am using a wake lock. I've tried using the MediaPlayer and the SoundPool with no success. Is there some kind of permission that I'm missing? (I already have WAKE_LOCK, DISABLE_KEYGUARD, and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permissions.)

When debugging using the SoundPool I perform the load which returns a valid sound ID integer (1), but the onLoadComplete listener (this is where the sound gets played) is never fired. It fires just fine when the device is awake.

Anyone out there have any ideas or have run into the same problem?

Comment: Found the solution! I had the call to play the audio in the onCreate() method of the class. I moved it to onResume() as this is when you know the device is fully awake and the activity is visible, on top and in focus.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! I had the call to play the audio in the onCreate() method of the class. I moved it to onResume() as this is when you know the device is fully awake and the activity is visible, on top and in focus.

Comment: You could also use onStart() since it's always called after onCreate() which is not always the case with onResume(). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem. The way I solved this was reading your answer, but also checking the activity flow by logging what was happening. Basically `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`, `onPause`, `onStop`, `onStart`, `onResume` was being fired in that order. This was an activity that was started as an alarm screen.

I kept the initialization code in the `onStart` method, making sure to use `.prepare()` instead of `prepareAsync()` since I'm using local sounds.

```
try {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting media player URI: " + alarmTone.toString());
    //mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, );
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception from media player: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Then inside the `onPause` and `onStop` methods, I added:

```
if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mMediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

Inside the `onResume` method I added the media playing code:

```
if (mMediaPlayer != null && !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Playing alarm through Media Player");
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Huzzah, it works!